# How to downgrade php from 5.5 to 5.3

Tags: php, xampp

Is there a way to downgrade php 5.5 to 5.3 in xampp? I searched on google but every one just tell me to uninstall xampp and install an older version. Could I have php 5.5 downgrade to 5.3 without reinstall xampp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there way to use two PHP versions in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Short answer is no.

XAMPP is normally built around a specific PHP version to ensure plugins and modules are all compatible and working correctly.

If your project specifically needs PHP 5.3 - the cleanest method is simply reinstalling an older version of XAMPP with PHP 5.3 packaged into it.

[XAMPP 1.7.7](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.7.7/) was their last update before moving off PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 9):

Long answer: it is **possible**!

1. Temporarily rename existing xampp folder
2. Install xampp 1.7.7 into xampp folder
   name
3. Folder containing just installed 1.7.7 distribution rename to different name and previously existing xampp folder rename back just to xampp.
4. In xampp folder rename **php** and **apache** folders to different names (I propose php_prev and apache_prev) so you can after switch back to them by renaming them back.
5. Copy apache and php folders from folder with xampp
   1.7.7 into xampp directory
6. In xampp directory comment line apache/conf/httpd.conf:458

   `#Include "conf/extra/httpd-perl.conf"`
7. In xampp directory do next replaces in files:

#### php/pci.bat:15

from

`"C:\xampp\php\.\php.exe" -f "\xampp\php\pci" -- %*`

to

`set XAMPPPHPDIR=C:\xampp\php
"%XAMPPPHPDIR%\php.exe" -f "%XAMPPPHPDIR%\pci" -- %*`

#### php/pciconf.bat:15

from

`"C:\xampp\php\.\php.exe" -f "\xampp\php\pciconf" -- %*`

to

`set XAMPPPHPDIR=C:\xampp\php
"%XAMPPPHPDIR%\.\php.exe" -f "%XAMPPPHPDIR%\pciconf" -- %*`

#### php/pear.bat:33

from

`IF "%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%"=="" SET "PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=C:\xampp\php\.\php.exe"`

to

`IF "%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%"=="" SET "PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=C:\xampp\php\php.exe"`

#### php/peardev.bat:33

from

`IF "%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%"=="" SET "PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=C:\xampp\php\.\php.exe"`

to

`IF "%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%"=="" SET "PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=C:\xampp\php\php.exe"`

#### php/pecl.bat:32

from

`IF "%PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR%"=="" SET "PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR=C:\xampp\php"
IF "%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%"=="" SET "PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=C:\xampp\php\.\php.exe"`

to

`IF "%PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR%"=="" SET "PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR=C:\xampp\php\"
IF "%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%"=="" SET "PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=C:\xampp\php\php.exe"`

#### php/phar.phar.bat:1

from

`%~dp0php.exe %~dp0pharcommand.phar %*`

to

`"%~dp0php.exe" "%~dp0pharcommand.phar" %*`

Enjoy new XAMPP with PHP 5.3

Checked by myself in XAMPP 5.6.31, 7.0.15 & 7.1.1 with XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2

Answer (score 3):

It is possible! Yes

In many cases, you might want to use XAMPP with a different PHP version than the one that comes preinstalled.
You might do this to get the benefits of a newer version of PHP, or to reproduce bugs using an earlier
version of PHP.

To use a different version of PHP with XAMPP, follow these steps:

> 1. Download a [binary build](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/) of the PHP version that you wish to use from the PHP website, and extract the contents of the compressed
>      archive file to your XAMPP installation directory (usually, C:\xampp).
>      Ensure that you give it a different directory name to avoid
>      overwriting the existing PHP version. For example, in this tutorial,
>      we’ll call the new directory `C:\xampp\php5-6-0`. **NOTE** : Ensure that the
>      PHP build you download matches the Apache build (VC9 or VC11) in your
>      XAMPP platform.
> 2. Within the new directory, rename the php.ini-development file to php.ini. If you prefer to use production settings, you could instead
>      rename the php.ini-production file to php.ini.
> 3. Edit the httpd-xampp.conf file in the apache\conf\extra\ subdirectory of your XAMPP installation directory. Within this file,
>      search for all instances of the old PHP directory path and replace
>      them with the path to the new PHP directory created in Step 1. In
>      particular, be sure to change the lines

```
    LoadFile "/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
    LoadFile "/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
    LoadModule php5_module "/xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

> to

```
    LoadFile "/xampp/php5-6-0/php5ts.dll"
    LoadFile "/xampp/php5-6-0/libpq.dll"
    LoadModule php5_module "/xampp/php5-6-0/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

> **NOTE** : Remember to adjust the file and directory paths above to reflect
>   valid paths on your system.
>
> 4. Restart your Apache server through the XAMPP control panel for your changes to take effect. The new version of PHP should now be active.
>      To verify this, browse to the URL
>      `http://localhost/xampp/phpinfo.php`, which displays the output of the
>      phpinfo() command, and check the version number at the top of the
>      page.

Comment: As I won't be caring too much about the other modules, yes, your answer suits me. =] Thank you.

Comment: Just another comment, apparently it should work that way but it doesn't. MySQL module cannot be loaded for some reason. Alternative: install a XAMPP version with php5.6 and copy the php folder. You can uninstall the older version and just use that folder. =)

Comment: I just did and it worked a like a charm. Thank you so much :) You made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

I did this in my local environment. Wasn't difficult but obviously it was done in "unsupported" way.

To do the downgrade you need just to download php 5.3 from http://php.net/releases/ (zip archive), than go to xampp folder and copy subfolder "php" to e.g. php5.5 (just for backup). Than remove content of the folder php and unzip content of zip archive downloaded from php.net. The next step is to adjust configuration (php.ini) - you can refer to your backed-up version from php 5.5. After that just run xampp control utility - everything should work (at least worked in my local environment). I didn't found any problem with such installation, although I didn't tested this too intensively.

Comment: @AngshuGuha try restarting apache.

Answer (score 0):

I just used a very simpler way for this and I just put it here if it could help anyone else.

I just had so much data on my database and I didn't want to transfer my whole Database so I just installed an older version of XAMPP with the PHP version that I required in a new directory (example:XAMPP-OLD) then I opened two control panel of 2 different version of XAMPP and start the MYSQL from the Newer version and Start Apache from the older version to use the other version of PHP.

just keep in mind to transfer files to the other XAMPP folder