# Is there way to use two PHP versions in XAMPP?

Tags: php, xampp

We are running XAMPP with PHP 7.0 because our new products requires PHP 7.

But there are old projects which use functions like `mysql_connect`, etc. Those are removed in PHP 7.0.

So, is there a way to easily change PHP versions in XAMPP?

> **Note**: Please don't suggest to upgrade old project to compatible with new versions because I am not in a position to do it because of that
>   decisions I can't get as a developer (just an employee).

Comment: I dont Think there is a workaround to what you want to do other than upgrading.  Also you shouldn't be finding ways to make old and deprecated API's compatible.  They should be removed totally.  Obviously that's a lot of work, but it would guarantee peace of mind

Comment: I stop and start Apache when I want to switch PHP versions in MAMP.  It's a pain, but it works.

Comment: you could dual boot

Comment: you can create virtual host then specify php version for each one

Comment: Can't flag it as duplicate, but this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757122/running-php-5-x-and-php-7-0-at-the-same-time-in-my-windows @I am the Most Stupid Person

Comment: I've posted a solution where you can download any version of PHP into its own folder, and configure Apache to use it. Try it and let me know if that meets your needs.

Comment: I have adopted the following solution with only 1 XAMPP installation:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757122/running-php-5-x-and-php-7-0-at-the-same-time-in-my-windows/45708158#45708158

what do you think?

Comment: Do you actually need to be able to run both PHP versions side by side at the same time in production, or do you just need to switch between them on your development workstation? I'm asking because your question seems to suggest the former (or at least doesn't explicitly rule it out), whereas most of the answers below address only the latter case.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I want to switch between them on your development workstation. Simply I want to use PHP 5 when I am doing Project A, I want PHP 7 when I am doing Project B. Even hugest rated answer isn't working, I can't find it... And many users..

Comment: What if you can use different versions of `PHP` for different directories under `htdocs` directory? Check out the simplest setup instructions I posted [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp#49586592).

Comment: And while you are at it, I hope you know the risks (of SQL Injection) of using `mysql_` commands. Use PDO or `mysqli_` instead. More info here https://www.sitepoint.com/migrate-from-the-mysql-extension-to-pdo/

Comment: will docker work in this scenario

Answer (score 334):

### Why switch between PHP versions when you can use *multiple PHP versions* at the same time with *a single xampp installation*?

**With a single xampp installation, you have 4 options:**

1. **Run an older PHP version for only the directory of your old project:** This will serve the purpose most of the time. You may have one or two old projects that you intend to run with an older PHP version. Just configure xampp to run an older PHP version for only those project directories.
2. **Run an older PHP version on a separate port of xampp:** Sometimes you may be upgrading an old project to the latest PHP version and at the same time you need to run the same project back and forth between the new PHP version and the old PHP version. To do this you can set an older PHP version on a different port (say 8056) so when you go to `http://localhost/any_project/`, xampp runs PHP 7 and when you go to `http://localhost:8056/any_project/` xampp runs PHP 5.6.
3. **Run an older PHP version on a virtualhost:** You can create a virtualhost like localhost56 to run PHP 5.6 while you can use PHP 7 on localhost.

### Lets set it up

**Step 1:** Download PHP

So you have PHP 7 running under xampp, you want to add an older PHP version to it (say PHP 5.6). Download the nts (Non Thread Safe) version of the PHP zip archive from [php.net](http://php.net/downloads.php) (see [archive](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/) for older versions) and extract the files under `c:\xampp\php56`. The thread safe version does not include php-cgi.exe.

**Step 2:** Configure `php.ini`

Open the file `c:\xampp\php56\php.ini` in notepad. If the file does not exist, copy `php.ini-development` to `php.ini` and open it in notepad. Then uncomment the following line:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

Also if the following line exists in Apache config `httpd-xampp.conf`

```
SetEnv PHPRC "\\path\\to\\xampp\\php"
```

comment it out with with a leading # (hash character).

**Step 3:** Configure apache

Open xampp control panel, click the config button for apache, and click `Apache (httpd-xampp.conf)`. A text file will open. Put the following settings at the bottom of the file:

```
ScriptAlias /php56 "C:/xampp/php56"
Action application/x-httpd-php56-cgi /php56/php-cgi.exe
<Directory "C:/xampp/php56">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

***Note:*** *You can add more versions of PHP to your xampp installation following step 1 to 3 if you want.*

**Step 4 (option 1):** *[Add Directories to run a specific PHP version]*

Now you can set directories that will run in PHP 5.6. Just add the following at the bottom of the config file (`httpd-xampp.conf` from Step 3) to set directories.

```
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\my_old_project1">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php56-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\my_old_project2">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php56-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

**Step 4 (option 2):** *[Run an older PHP version on a separate port]*

Now to to set PHP v5.6 on port 8056, add the following code to the bottom of the config file (`httpd-xampp.conf` from Step 3).

```
Listen 8056
<VirtualHost *:8056>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php56-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 4 (option 3):** *[Run an older PHP version on a virtualhost]*

To create a virtualhost (localhost56) on a directory (htdocs56) to use PHP v5.6 on http://localhost56, create directory htdocs56 at your desired location and
add localhost56 to your hosts file ([see how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17893591)),
then add the following code to the bottom of the config file (`httpd-xampp.conf` from Step 3).

```
<VirtualHost localhost56:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs56"
    ServerName localhost56
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs56">
        Require all granted    
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php56-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Finish:** Save and Restart Apache

Save and close the config file. Restart apache from the xampp control panel. If you went for option 2, you can see the additional port(8056) listed in your xampp control panel.

[image: xampp control panel showing apache running with configured ports]

Comment: Hi, I was trying this method (Step 4 Option 1), but get an error malformed header from script 'php-cgi.exe': Bad header: <br />, any ideas what could the problem be ?

Comment: @Priyanshu is your PHP installation OK? Can you run PHP files from command line like `php somefile.php` wihout any errors?

Comment: He needs to set name of the desired version  of php folder to php and other php folder to another name

Comment: Same problem encountered, couldn't get over it. I presume the php installation was okay, since I hadn't changed a single thing - simply followed the instructions. Any ideas what could be causing the issue?

Comment: Is there any reference for where you found out how to do this? I'm just getting a blank page and I can't figure out where I've gone wrong

Comment: Has anyone managed to get past the Server Error: malformed header from script 'php-cgi.exe': Bad header: <br /> ?

Comment: @Leon that error results when your PHP script encounters errors. Open PHP interactive mode (`php -a`) to see if there is any error.

Comment: @Munim I have XAMPP v 5.6.8 installed. I want to run PHP 7.3 as well. I followed the instructions above. In httpd-xampp.conf / httpd-vhosts.conf / index.php I have the following: https://pastebin.com/D7Sp8G78 - PHP Interactive mode (php -a) for PHP 7.3 works OK.

Comment: @Leon do you have php-cgi.exe file in your PHP directory? have you downloaded the non-thread safe version of PHP?

Comment: @MunimMunna - Yes and Yes. I downloaded this file: php-7.3.0-nts-Win32-VC15-x64.zip (VC15 x64 Non Thread Safe ) from here: https://windows.php.net/download#php-7.3

Comment: @Leon PHP interactive mode does not show any errors or warnings?

Comment: @MunimMunna - No errors. I did this from Windows cmd: cd to C:\xampp\php73 > then "php -a". First I see: "Interactive shell - php >" then after echo 5+8; it prints 13

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186296/discussion-between-munim-munna-and-leon).

Comment: This is now working for me after @MunimMunna updated the post above. As suggested I had to comment out the SetEnv PHPRC line to stop the malformed error notice. Special thanks to Munim for his outstanding help in getting this working.

Comment: The answer no longer even contains the code to include `SetEnv PHPRC` so I can't comment it out, yet I am still getting that error. :(

Comment: Nevermind - I just realised that line was an _already existing_ line in the file, not one that was added via the the instrcutions.

Comment: There is a small issue on Step 2.
On Windows you have to use a full path like C:\php56\ext

Comment: Hi. when i run localhost:8056, I get object not found page.

Comment: @MunimMunna Thanks for your detail explanation. It helped lot. I tried with windows 10 and wmapserver.

Comment: Run an older PHP version on a virtualhost it's not working.

Comment: Step4 Option1 seems to work well according to phpinfo, I just need to workout why my Windows cmd is searching in the wrong XAMPP path even though I've updated Environmental Variables Path.

Comment: someone able to work multiple php version with xdebug? i got `Error message:
End of script output before headers: php-cgi.exe`

Comment: Just perfect! I looked everywhere, but couldn't find something remotely as concise as yours. Thanks for saving my weekend.

Comment: Excelent explanation! very usefull for old clientes. and dont need to change the version every time! thanks a lot!

Comment: I also get: 
End of script output before headers: php-cgi.exe
I am using XAMPP 3.2.4
Where you able to fix this?
@MunimMunna Maybe you know any fix for this?

Comment: `  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted` Added additional permissions to the localhost56 option

Comment: Thank you this works for me, only add the config file name in Step 4 (option 1) and Step 4 (option 2). Except this everything is clear

Comment: @Norman @YdB - I encountered the same error 500 **Error message: End of script output before headers: php-cgi.exe**, but only if I make an request like this: `info.php?0=foo` (a number as parameter key) having xdebug enabled. Were you able to solve it somehow?

Comment: @marcus nope, instead of having multiple PHP versions in one XAMPP, I installed a seperate XAMPP for older PHP version.. This worked for me..

Comment: when i uncomment extension=mysqli i get the error End of script output before headers

Comment: I'm running in to can't load dll when setup php 5.2, it's still trying to pull from php instead of php52 directory instead of the one I pointed it to. Is there something that has changed with XAMPP configuration?  Well,more details, I noticed it was the x86 version, so I tried 5.5.38 x64 version and it works, but really I need old 5.2.x version since everything needs mysql_pconnect() and the rest, no time to reprogram.   Is there a 5.2.x version that will work in XAMPP ?

Comment: @user3161924 I'm having the exact same problem and am wondering the same thing... Perhaps something has changed for the past two years causing this misconfiguration, but I'd also love to know why it happens and how to fix it.

Comment: Hello, same as @nas. When i run localhost:8056/foo/, I get object not found page. Does anybody knows why ?

Comment: After the execution of the above steps I still got the php version which came with xampp, so I then followed this answer by [Adam Endvy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50402648/8280010) which resolved the problem.

Comment: Just installed PHP 8.0.2 using this method. The only glitch was that I'd copied extension names from a PHP 7 ini, so be aware that the extension for GD has changed it's name from gd2 to gd. https://php.watch/versions/8.0/gd2-gd-windows - after changing that all is good.

Comment: Note: At least with PHP 7+, you need the thread-safe version, otherwise Apache won't run it. They all contain php-cgi.exe

Comment: Instead of editing the conf or setup a virtualhost you can define the php version in the .htaccess.
e.g. PHP 7.4
Add AddHandler x-httpd-php74 .php
The number after x-httpd-php belongs to the php version numbers in format major minior without a dot between them.
So 74 belongs to PHP 7.4; 56 to PHP 5.6 ...

Comment: This worked for 7.4 when I used the thread-safe version--after trying _everything_!

Comment: I used option 1 to add a PHP 7.4  on my local environment. It works just great. The only problem, that I noticed is that with the XAMMP original PHP 7.3 the landing page load for 0.9s, but wit added PHP 7.4 the landing page load for 2.33s. This is a big difference in performance. Did someone know why this happened and is there some fix? Or I just need to install a new XAMPP to have better performance?

Comment: Using PHP 7.4 with option 2 (on a separate port) did the job for me. One thing to notice is that I needed to use Sublime Text (or your text editor of choice) to create the php.ini file in the php74 folder, because creating a text field and renaming it to php.ini didn't work for me. Edit: I am using XAMPP 8.1.1 on Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Usefull, i could add PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.3 successfully using option 2, but with PHP 8.1 , I get "object not found" for localhost:8081 and "Acces forbidden" for localhost:8081/test/index.php.

Comment: I've found the scource of my previously posted problem: use a folder without a ".". I extracted the downloaded zip-file directly into c:\xampp. Then the corresponding php-folder isn't foud, but when I chenged the name into "php81" and redid the steps, all worked well.

Comment: I can't even find the php.ini file in the downloaded php folder (ver 8.1.3) so I can't do step 1. the link I'm using is from https://windows.php.net/download#php-8.1 . any help??

Comment: @dapidmini You probably need to copy/rename `php.ini-development` or `php.ini-production` to `php.ini`.

Comment: Download from here, then it will work. https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/

Comment: I have to run one of my laravel project on php 8. I have installed xampp with php 7.4.29 in D drive. Followed all steps as per given and from optional step I have chosen option 2. New virtual port 8010 is also added in control panel as shown in image. But when I serve project with php artisan serve --port=8010, it shows fatal error. Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". You are running 7.4.29. in D:\xampp\htdocs\project-name\vendor\composer\platform_check.php on line 24

Comment: @KhushalNayani `php artisan serve` command does not use php configured for xampp. it uses the php in your PATH. Run `php --version` to see which php is activated by PATH.

Comment: @MunimMunna yeah while running php --version it is showing php version 7.4.29. Is there any better way to just run this particular laravel project in php 8 ?

Comment: **at the bottom of the file** -> Inside or outside the `<IfModule>`?

Comment: I have changed from `xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`  lines for PHP 7.4 and 8.2.1 . `LoadModule php_module "c:/xamppnew/php8/php8apache2_4.dll"
#LoadModule php7_module "C:/xamppnew/php/php7apache2_4.dll"` The version has changes but when I open phpmyadmin , It gives blank . I am using windows . Is there any solution?

Comment: Any getting the bad header error, make sure to comment the line PHPRC. Also, make sure to update extension_directory from php.ini of your alternate php version. So, if you are running PHP8 as the primary version and php7.2 as alternate, you need to update php.ini of php7.2 like this: extension_dir="E:\xampp\php7.2\ext"

Answer (score 99):

You can download whatever versions of PHP you need and place them into their own directories, e.g.

`c:\php5\`

`c:\php7\`

All you need to do is tell your web server (Apache) which version of PHP to use, which you do by loading the appropriate module. In Apache you can do this by finding the file `httpd.conf` and then editing the appropriate line:

`LoadModule php7_module c:\php7\libphp7.so`

You'll have to figure out the correct paths of course - this is just for illustration.

Save `httpd.conf` and restart your server. Note, if you don't restart it, the changes won't take effect.

There's no GUI switch to be able to do this, you need to edit the `.conf` file and then restart Apache. Doing this only takes a couple of seconds and you could even comment out a version so "switching" only takes a couple of keystrokes, e.g.

*Use PHP 5:*

```
LoadModule php5_module c:\php5\libphp5.so
#LoadModule php7_module c:\php7\libphp7.so
```

*Use PHP 7:*

```
#LoadModule php5_module c:\php5\libphp5.so
LoadModule php7_module c:\php7\libphp7.so
```

**You do not need multiple versions of XAMPP**, or to dual boot, or use a different machine, or any of the other "solutions" that have suggested convoluted workarounds. The OP wants to use XAMPP and tell it which version of PHP to use. This is the quickest and most efficient way of doing it, and only requires one XAMPP installation.

**Edit 1-Nov-2017:** Apparently some people are saying there's no `.so` files on Windows. The answer I gave was adapted from how I have things set up on my Mac (which does use `.so` files instead of `.dll`). The principle of the answer however is still exactly correct. You are using Apache's configuration file, `httpd.conf` to specify *where* the PHP module (`.so` or `.dll`) is located on your system. So the only difference for Windows would be the file name and/or path location. The answer I've given is also correct for a vanilla installation of Apache/PHP (without XAMPP at all).

Comment: I think your answer is the best one and I am goint to acepected it. But I could not found a similar line to 'LoadModule php7_module c:\php7\libphp7.so' in `httpd/conf`

Comment: Do a search in the conf file for `LoadModule`. They are usually listed together. You will not see one for `php7_` unless it's already configured for PHP 7. More likely to see `php5_` or something similar. The modules usually have the file extension `.so`.

Comment: I agained check. I could not find it. Can you please check my httpd.conf file. This is the copy of it.  http://freetexthost.com/sjxz4lh1i5 Please let me know if you find that line which should I changed.

Comment: There is not any libphp7.so into XAMPP and any LoadModule string into conf file

Comment: I also could not find this entry.  I also searched my php directory and could not find any .so files at all.

Comment: The information I've given was adapted from how I have things set up on my Mac. The OP doesn't say what OS they were using. If you are using Windows maybe it's a `.dll` file (instead of `.so`)? You'll have to do some of your own investigation work. But the principle of the answer is correct - you use the Apache config file (`httpd.conf`) to specify where the PHP module is located. Do some research into `LoadModule` for XAMPP/Windows, or whatever system you're using. On my Mac it's configured by `LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/php5/libphp7.so` - it's just the file/path that will differ.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson I can't find this line as well. Anyone found this missing line?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson Apparently it's not a simple one-liner, it's going to be a many line replacements. This site is very detailed: https://silas.com.ng/multiple-php-version-xampp-windows/

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson Yes!

Comment: In v3.2.2 the line is located in xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf

Comment: It is not just one line. You have to edit a good portion of httpd-xampp.conf. So it is better to switch entire httpd-xampp.conf  each time you have to.

Comment: For `windows` users using `WampServer`, they can find `httpd.conf` in *wamp/bin/apache/apachexxx/conf/httpd.conf*. This link is also helping further: https://superuser.com/questions/335941/how-to-add-new-php-version-to-wamp/569472

Comment: I  dont understand why the answer is still not accepted.

Comment: For Windows users with PHP version greater than or equal to 7.2: the filename is `httpd-xampp.conf` and it is located in `/xampp/apache/conf/extra`

Comment: This option does not work, I saw many sites providing this solution with many lookouts but to no avail

Comment: @LucasM.Oliveira it does work, which is why 95 people have upvoted it. Maybe the problem is how you've tried to set it up. Without details nobody can help you.

Comment: I have added from `xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf` lines `#LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
LoadModule php_module "c:/xampp/php8/php8apache2_4.dll"` The version has changed but when I open phpmyadmin , it gives me blank page .  Why ?

Comment: @Andy Did you have any luck addingh PHP8.2+ as well? I'm getting endless missing mysqli error even though these extensions are uncommented and should be fine. It's getting a bit tiresome so I am curious if you have a fix for that as well?

Answer (score 50):

You can [download](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) and install two different xampps like I do: (first is php7 second is php5)
[image]

and if you don't want to do that, I suggest you use wamp and change versions like shown [here](http://blog.astemplates.com/change-php-version-wamp/).

Comment: Why would you do this? You're installing a lot of the same software again, just for a tiny difference (different version of PHP, when the rest of the software like Apache and MySQL is exactly the same). I've posted a solution where you can simply use 1 installation of XAMPP and point it at the appropriate version of PHP.

Comment: _Why would you do this?_ because it works, and I don't mind having multiple apache and mysql installed if it saves some time.

Comment: no need to care about best practices here, it's a local environment

Comment: I use this aproach, in adition, i recommend you to add specific start menu entries for each installation, like: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\XAMPP56 and C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\XAMPP7 for example

Comment: If this is not a good solution why you don't post a correct solution? Actually is very difficult install 2 versions on the same xampp and all the solutions here are wrong...

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend using Docker, this allows you to split the environment into various components and mix and match the ones you want at any time.

Docker will allow you to run one container with MySQL, another with PHP.  As they are separate images you can have two containers, one PHP 5 another PHP 7, you start up which ever one you wish and port 80 can be mapped to both containers.

https://hub.docker.com has a wide range of preconfigured images which you can install and run without much hassle.

I've also added [portainer](https://github.com/portainer/portainer) as an image, which allows you to manage the various aspects of your docker setup - from within a docker image (I did start this container on startup to save me having to use the command line).  It doesn't do everything for you and sometimes it's easier to configure and launch the images for the first time from the command line, but once setup you can start and stop them through a web interface.

It's also possible to run both containers at the same time and map separate ports to each.  So port 80 can be mapped to PHP 5 and 81 to PHP 81 (Or PHP 7 if your watching this in 2017).

There are various tutorials on how to install Docker( https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/) and loads of other 'how to' type things. Try http://www.masterzendframework.com/docker-development-environment/ for a development environment configuration.

Comment: I second this.  Do your company a favor and get Docker running.  Switch PHP versions, onboard new developers faster, make deployment easier, and no surprises in production.

Comment: *and 81 to PHP 81.* do you mean PHP 7? I think we're some way off PHP 81 yet :)

Comment: Errrr... I really meant 81 (I'm ensuring my answer is future proof :-/ )

Comment: @NigelRen I haven't down-voted it but would guess that it's because you're proposing using a completely different solution (Docker) rather than addressing how it's possible within XAMPP - which it definitely is. Your answer is a (very good) alternative solution to the problem, but not an answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: FWIW in 2021: Docker is quite unusable on Windows, its VERY slow due to the WSL module which appears to have quirks with accessing files. You are better off with xampp or wamp.

Comment: @Flame, I would be interested to see what articles back up your experience.

Comment: @NigelRen Sorry no sources except my own experience. I tried setting it up 2 weeks ago for a Laravel project. Got everything running but the requests still took 15-30s each. I double checked any configuration that I might've misconfigured, but there wasnt. I took this from my browser history: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4197 . I tried the legacy WSL which sped it up but still within the 5-10s range for the simplest PHP requests (including composer autoloading etc). End result: I reverted back to using WAMP with 200ms load time (Laravel app). It will likely work much better on Linux

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can. I assume you have a xampp already installed. So,

- Close all xampp instances. Using task manager stop apache and mysqld.
- Then rename the xampp to xampp1 or something after xampp name.
- Now Download the other xampp version. Create a folder name xampp only. Install the downloaded xampp there.
- Now depending on the xampp version of your requirement, just rename the target folder to xampp only and other folder to different name.

***That's how I am working with multiple xampp installed***

Comment: Not sure why this gets downvotet as this answer does work and is exactly what the question is asking about. Silent downvoting without suggesting improvements isnt a clever thing at all in general.

Comment: @FabianSchöner Thanks. I dont know why I was getting downvoted on this answer.

Comment: The reason it's been downvoted is because someone has already posted exactly this answer. And secondly, it's a totally un-necessary way of doing things since you're installing ALL the same software again just to get a small difference. It's possible - as stated in the answer I posted - to use 1 installation of XAMPP and then configure it to use different versions of PHP.

Comment: For developers working with different projects with different dependencies and have less time to go over with so much details, this solution is the best option. I didn't have thought this way is actually easier until I've seen this.

Answer (score 11):

I use Uniserver.

It has this feature built in.

http://www.uniformserver.com/

It's that simple.

> The Uniform Server is a free lightweight WAMP server solution for Windows. Less than 24MB, modular design, includes the latest versions of Apache2, Perl5, PHP (switch between PHP53, PHP54, PHP55 or PHP56), MySQL5 or MariaDB5, phpMyAdmin or Adminer4. No installation required! No registry dust! Just unpack and fire up!

It even runs off a flash drive.  Has cron emulation, support for perl, mariaDB, a couple versions of Mysql, filezilla server and a few other things.

[image]

Comment: I'm getting a virus alert. Win32/Uwamson.A!ml

Answer (score 10):

Unless it has to be absolutely and definitely XAMPP, you can try to get what you want with WAMP.
WAMP is pretty much the same thing in different package.

Once you have it installed, you can just switch between php versions here:

[image]

You can install as many versions of PHP as you need.

**Here's how it is done in detail.**

Just go here: [WAMP download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/)

Then select your base server, e.g. latest with php7.

Then, when WAMP 3 is installed, go to folder: **addons** and select php version (or versions) you are after. They offer php flavors starting from php 5.3.29, which should work with mysql_connect.

To install addon, during installation (double click exe file) just point to folder where you have your WAMP 3 installed.

Then you can use content of other folders, like: **applications** etc. to add more functionality

Everything's interfaced, so you can concentrate on coding and not hacking your environment.

Answer (score 9):

I am working on a ten years old project at work. So 5.6 is my default. There are also older small projects which only works with 5.2 and I also want to work on new versions for my personal projects with 7.3.8

Here is what I did to add 5.2 and 7.3.8 on default 5.6 version.

1 - Downloaded php TS versions ;

- v7.3.8(latest) : https://windows.php.net/download/
- v5.2 :  https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=7349

2 - Extracted to c:\xampp\php738 and c:\xampp\php52 folder in order

3 - Added these lines to the bottom of httpd-xampp.conf (or httpd.conf) ;

*** IMPORTANT NOTICE : You should NOT use script alias name as your target folder name,
they must be different. (for instance /php7x is ok , /php7 is not)

## PHP 7.3.8 for folder D:\www\php7

```
ScriptAlias /php7x "C:/xampp/php738"
Action application/x-httpd-php7-cgi /php7x/php-cgi.exe
<Directory "C:/xampp/php738">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "D:\www\php7">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php7-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

## PHP 5.2 for folder D:\www\php52

```
ScriptAlias /phpold "C:/xampp/php52"
Action application/x-httpd-phpold-cgi /phpold/php-cgi.exe
<Directory "C:/xampp/php52">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "D:\www\php52">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-phpold-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Some helpful notes :

- If you have troubles with php5.x while using composer switch terminal to 7.3.8
- If you want to make php 7.3.8 your default command line php interpreter on windows just change your windows environment path for php to the 7.3.8 folder path.
- Don't forget to edit your relevant php.ini confs as you need in each version folder.

And as a last bonus note , if you need to set a virtual host with any of versions you can use similar approach. 
A sample laravel vhost conf for php 7.3.8;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@laravel.local
DocumentRoot "D:\www\vhosts\laravel.local\public"
ServerName  laravel.local
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
 SetHandler application/x-httpd-php7-cgi # escape for default php version
#SetHandler application/x-httpd-phpold-cgi # unescape for php 5.2
</FilesMatch>

ErrorLog "logs/laravel.local.log"
CustomLog "logs/laravel.local.log" combined
```

Thanks to @Munim Munna for detailed answer, I wanted to share a solid sample with the important notice above.

Comment: Isn't it Non thread safe?

Comment: Right, for windows apache fast-cgi NTS used

Answer (score 6):

You can have two different versions of XAMPP.

- Download those files from https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html and install into a directory of your choice, for example in C:\5.6.31\xampp and C:\7.1.18\xampp.
- After every installation go to installed directory (ex. C:\5.6.31\xampp, C:\7.1.18\xampp) and start the "setup_xampp.bat" and you should see something like
  [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rOyU.jpg)
- You can make shortcuts of "xampp-control.exe" on your desktop (right click on "xampp-control.exe" Send to -> Desktop) and rename shortcuts for ex. "xampp 5.6.31" and "xampp 7.1.8".
- Start XAMPP control panel with double-click on "xampp-control.exe" or previously created shortcut and start Apache and MySQL servers.
- To test installiation open your browser and type 127.0.0.1 or localhost in the location bar. You should see XAMPP start screen.
- Do not open more then one XAMPP control panel.
- XAMPP uninstall? Simply remove the "xampp" Directory.
  But before please shutdown the apache and mysql.
- That's all. You can use different php versions opening corresponding XAMPP control panel.

Comment: If it's really possible do it with 1 installation why you don't post a solution? Actually is very difficult install 2 versions and all the solutions here are wrong...

Comment: @Andy If DB is not so large, double install is a viable option. But your answer got my upvote.

Answer (score 6):

run this in Command Prompt windows (cmd.exe).

```
set PATH=C:\xampp\php;%PATH%
```

change it depending where you put the php 7 installation.

Comment: After I followed [Munim Munna](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49586592/8280010) answer in cmd I got only the php version which comes with xampp. After I executed your script in cmd, the php version changed. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

**I was also in the same situation recently and I solved it with the following steps:**

**Step 1**: Download the nts (Non Thread Safe) version of the PHP zip archive from [php.net](https://php.net). Then extract it in xampp folder, same level as default php folder. The xampp folder will now look like this:

[image]

**Step 2:**

- Open the downloaded `php` folder. Coppy file `php.ini-development` to `php.ini` and open it with any editor (notepad, notepadd++...). Press key `Ctrl+F` combination and find text: `extension_dir = "ext"` then uncomment this line by remove the semicolon at the beginning of the line.

[image]

- Do the same to uncomment the following lines: `extension=curl` `extension=ftp` `extension=fileinfo` `extension=mysqli` `extension=openssl` `extension=pdo_mysql`

[image]

**Step 3:**

- Go to the `xampp` folder, open the file `httpd-xampp.conf` with the path `{disk_name}/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf` ( replace `{disk name}` with drive disk where you installed xampp).
- For example, I installed xampp in drive D, the path to open the file
  `httpd-xampp.conf` will now be `D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf`.
- Or simlier, open xampp control panel, click the config button for apache, and click Apache (`httpd-xampp.conf`).

[image]

- Next, add the following code at the end of the `httpd-xampp.conf` file, then change `/php8_1` and `D:/xampp/php8_1/` to the name and path to your php folder.

```
ScriptAlias /php8_1/ "D:/xampp/php8_1/" 
Action application/x-httpd-php8_1-cgi "/php8_1/php-cgi.exe" 
<Directory "D:/xampp/php8_1">
       AllowOverride None
       Options None
       Require all denied
       <Files "php-cgi.exe">
           Require all granted
       </Files>     SetEnv PHPRC "D:/xampp/php8_1" 
</Directory>
```

[image]

- For example: If your `php` folder name is `php6_5` and folder path is `C:/xampp/php6_5/` then the code will be:

```
ScriptAlias /php6_5 "C:/xampp/php6_5/"
Action application/x-httpd-php6_5-cgi "/php6_5/php-cgi.exe"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php6_5">
     AllowOverride None
     Options None
     Require all denied
        <Files "php-cgi.exe">
            Require all granted
        </Files>
        SetEnv PHPRC "C:/xampp/php6_5/"
 </Directory>
```

- **Note**: You can add more versions of PHP to your `XAMPP` installation following step 1 to 3 if you want.

**Step 4:** Add directories to run a specific PHP version

- Just add the following at the bottom of the config file (`httpd-xampp.conf` from Step 3) to set directories.

```
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project1">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5_6-cgi //replace php5_6 with your version php
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project2">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php8_1-cgi //replace php8_1with your version php
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

- You can see instruction in the image below

[image]

**Step 5:** Save and restart `XAMPP`

- Save and close the config file. Restart apache from the xampp control panel. If you want to check if the configuration is successful, create a `index.php` file and `<?php echo phpinfo()` to check the php version.

> Now, I will show my result

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to have multiple versions of PHP set up with a single XAMPP installation. The instructions below are working for Windows.

1. Install the latest XAMPP version for Windows (in my case it was with PHP 7.1)
2. Make sure that Apache is not running from XAMPP Control Panel
3. Rename the php directory in XAMPP install directory, such as `C:\xampp\php` become `C:\xampp\php-7.1.11`.
4. Download the version of PHP you'd like to run in addition (Eg: [PHP 5.4.45](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/))
5. Move the php directory from the version you downloaded to XAMPP install directory. Rename it so it includes the PHP version. Such as `C:\xampp\php-5.4.45`.

Now you need to edit XAMPP and Apache configuration :

6. In `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`, locate the XAMPP settings for PHP, you should change it to something such as :

Where you have to comment (with `#`) the other PHP versions so only one `Include` will be interpreted at the time.

```
#XAMPP settings PHP 7
Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf.7.1"

#XAMPP settings PHP 5.4.45
#Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf.5.4.45"
```

7. Now in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra` directory rename `httpd-xampp.conf` to `httpd-xampp.conf.7.1` and add a new configuration file for `httpd-xampp.conf.5.4.45`. In my case, I copied the conf file of another installation of XAMPP for php 5.5 as the syntax may be slightly different for each version.
8. Edit `httpd-xampp.conf.5.4.45` and `httpd-xampp.conf.7.1` and replace there all the reference to the `php` directory with the new `php-X.X` version. There are at least 10 changes to be made here for each file.
9. You now need to edit php.ini for the two versions. For example for php 7.1, edit `C:\xampp\php-7.1.11\php.ini` where you will replace the path of the php directory for `include_path`, `browscap`, `error_log`, `extension_dir`..

And that's it. You can now start Apache from XAMPP Control Panel. And to switch from a version to another, you need only to edit `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` and change the included PHP version before restarting Apache.

Comment: 6. I can't find any PHP settings inside httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these **easy steps**. I am currently running XAMPP on PHP 7.2 but need PHP 5.6 to work on old projects.

**STEP 1**

Download Thread Safe version of PHP on https://windows.php.net/download

Put files on your [Drive]:\xampp\php5.6

- Rename the folder depending on your new php version

**STEP 2**

Copy [Drive]:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf

Rename the file depending on the new php version and put it here: [Drive]:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp5.6.conf

**STEP 3**

Edit the newly created 'httpd-xampp5.6.conf'

Basically, you need to change All the PHP sources and .dll

Before

```
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

After

```
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php5.6/php5ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php5.6/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/xampp/php5.6/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

Here is my file: https://gist.github.com/mpalencia/f8a20c31bffb02fe20d371218c23d1ec

**STEP 4**

Edit the file [Drive]:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

Before

```
# XAMPP settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"
```

After

```
# XAMPP settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp5.6.conf"
```

- You can edit this line when switching to different version

**STEP 5**

Edit your PHP 5.6 configuration - php.ini

Add you extension directory:
extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php5.6\ext"

**STEP 6**

Start Apache

**STEP 7**

Edit PHP environment variable path on Windows

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the least technical answer to the question, but it's also the easiest to accomplish.

If you have two drives such as **C:** and **D:** you can install a separate instance of XAMPP on both drives with different php versions. This took me less than 10 mins to do and is least error prone.

I just create two desktop shortcuts to both xampp-control.exe and name the shortcuts after their php version. I hope this helps someone like me that prefers a very quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to share my new finding: https://laragon.org/docs/index.html

I just used it for 1 hour and it looks promising.

- You can add and switch PHP versions,
- it has one-click installers for Wordpress, laravel, etc
- it autocreates vhosts with the name of each app (eg. appname.test)
- you can select your current htdocs folder as the root www folder
- you just add other PHP versions extracting them in folders and selecting them from a list
- it auto reload apache after each change
- adding phpMyAdmin is as easy as download it and put it in {LARAGON_DIR}\etc\apps\phpMyAdmin, etc...

[Laragon DOCS](https://laragon.org/docs/index.html)

[How to add another PHP version to Laragon](https://forum.laragon.org/topic/166/tutorial-how-to-add-another-php-version-php-7-4-php-8-0-updated)

[How to add phpMyAdmin to Laragon](https://forum.laragon.org/topic/98/tutorial-how-to-add-phpmyadmin)

---

*I'm not affiliated in any way with Laragon. Just found it on Google looking for "XAMPP Windows alteratives"*

Comment: I want to add that Laragon is excellent - it knocks spots off Xampp. You can change PHP or MySql version in a few clicks. (It's not related to Laravel at all, silly idea calling it Lara....)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to waste your time with this configurations just use [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) :)

MAMP have a PHP version selection feature on interface.

Answer (score 2):

Simple and Easiest Steps is

- Install xampps whatever php version you want.
- Rename xampp folder in C:\xampp to C:\xampp74
  [image]
- Download and install another xampps like I do: (first is php7 second is php8)
- Now you have two different xampp  with different php version
  [image]
- Now whenever you want to change you just nned to follow

  - stop Apache and mysql and Quit xampp
    [image]
    [image]
  - Rename folder to xampp an change other xampp folder with it's version name to remember
    [image]
  - Again Start the Apache and mysql (some time it can't rename then restart and try)

Answer (score 1):

I do stuck with same problem at time of installing magento2 while it require ~7.3.0 but I have 7.4.1. So, I downgraded php version using this method.

Step 1: Download Php version from here nts version
https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/
and paste this version to c:\xampp\ as named 'php71'

Step 2: Setup Virtual Host Environment and do some other changes.
Go to "c:\xampp/\pache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf" and put code snippet at the end of line

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/crashcourse/"
    ServerName magento2.test
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/crashcourse/">
        Require all granted    
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php71-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

GO to "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" then edit the file with using admin privileges then add the code at end of line.

```
127.0.0.1 magento2.test
```

Go to you Apache Config file "c:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf" and paste below code at end of the line

```
ScriptAlias /php71 "C:/xampp/php71"
Action application/x-httpd-php71-cgi /php71/php-cgi.exe
<Directory "C:/xampp/php71">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    SetEnv PHPRC "C:/xampp/php71"
</Directory>
```

Now, all set.
Go to url: http://magento2.test all work fine!

Answer (score 1):

Versions of PHP can be specified in .htaccess files. This means that while most projects can be left to default to the global configuration in the httpd.conf file, specific projects can be set to a different version simply by editing .htaccess.

The advantage of using .htaccess is that different PHP versions can be used for different projects without needing to keep making changes to httpd.conf to specify which PHP is needed by different project directories. Instead, the change can be made directly within the project itself, simply by editing its .htaccess file.

The exact line needed will vary depending on your setup. For me, using Fast CGI, I just add the following line in the .htaccess file of those projects for which I want to use PHP 8 (PHP 7 is the default on my server).

```
FcgidWrapper "C:/xampp/php-8.0.6-nts-Win32-vs16-x64/php-cgi.exe -c C:/xampp/php-8.0.6-nts-Win32-vs16-x64" .php
```

The first part of the string references the PHP executable, while the `-c` option is for the directory path of the required php.ini file. If this is omitted, the globally configured php.ini will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Might i suggest using the [Xampp PHP Switcher](https://github.com/JackieDo/Xampp-PHP-Switcher) by [JackieDo](https://github.com/JackieDo).
After the very easy installation you can use the command `xphp switch [VERSION]` to change the php version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but I am using a batch to rename the PHP folders (a slightly modified version of the [phpswitch](https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpswitch/downloads) I found years ago).

You copy the different folders into your XAMPP installation. Each PHP folder (except for the active one) receives the version number as a suffix (eg. *php_5.6.32*). In **ALL** PHP folders, a file (PHP_VERSION) is created, which contains only the respective version number, so the Script can grab this information. But that's all described in the README.

Since PHP7 the *httpd-xampp.conf* loads the *php7ts.dll* instead of the *php5ts.dll*. So i had to extend the script (PHPSwitch.php) to rename these config-files too by following the same approach.

```
    $renameCur = new PHPSwitch_Rename($currInst['path'], $this->_cfg['phpInstallationsPath'] . $this->_cfg['phpDirName'] . '_' . $currInst['version']);
    $renameNew = new PHPSwitch_Rename($newInst['path'], $this->_cfg['phpInstallationsPath'] . $this->_cfg['phpDirName']);

    $apache_curent      = $this->_cfg["phpInstallationsPath"]."apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf";
    $apache_curent_rename   = $this->_cfg["phpInstallationsPath"]."apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp_".$currInst['version'].".conf";
    $apache_new             = $this->_cfg["phpInstallationsPath"]."apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp_".$newInst['version'].".conf";
    $apache_new_rename      = $this->_cfg["phpInstallationsPath"]."apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf";

    $renameCur_apache_conf = new PHPSwitch_Rename($apache_curent, $apache_curent_rename);
    $renameNew_apache_conf = new PHPSwitch_Rename($apache_new, $apache_new_rename);

    $transaction = new PHPSwitch_Rename_Transaction();
    $transaction->add($renameCur);
    $transaction->add($renameNew);
    $transaction->add($renameCur_apache_conf);
    $transaction->add($renameNew_apache_conf);
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing, so I googled how and came to stack overflow, where the OP was having the same issue... So my findings.. I tried renaming files from all different directions AND my conclusion was basically it's taking me too long. SOOOO I ended up just installing version 7 from here:

https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html
**(kill services and quit out of xampp before attempting)**

When asked where to put the directory name it like so (give it a different name):

[image]

and

DONEZO! Now just make sure to kill services and quit before swapping back and forth and you have 2 sterile XAMPP envs to play in..

Hooray! now I can actually get to work!

Comment: I think it is already suggested by 2 answers above, Maulik Gangani and og1842.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [php switcher](https://github.com/hugdx/multiple-php-version-with-xampp)

You can control php version to any your project you want via vhost config.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is the old post but I want to share there is library for still running mysql_connect() in PHP 7.
It works by overriding the real function (mysql_connect() is overridden by mysqli_connect() which work on this library).

I found from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eqd-jJu4sQ4

hopefully it helps