# installing two versions of php with xampp on ubuntu system

Tags: php, linux, xampp

I searched for how to install php5 and php7 on same machine but i didn't find the an answer.

I'm working on two different project one depend on php5 and the other work on php7

I use xampp on linux

how can i run two versions of php 5 & 7 on xampp @ linux ubuntu 16.04 machine ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there way to use two PHP versions in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp)

Comment: is the related article about linux ?? 
@Nic3500 ???

Comment: @MustafaAgamey yes it is for linux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution I've done

## Note :

at installing new version of xampp I got mysql errors

I think it because the version of mysql

## so make sure that backup all databases before that

1- install xampp with php 5 from the site

2- install xampp with php 7 from the site

to here we must have php5.so and php7.so in same dir

3- open /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf and add two line :

instead of one line of php 7

```
   LoadModule php7_module        modules/libphp7.so
   LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
```

4- before running xampp file just comment the undesired version

to run php 5 :

```
 #LoadModule php7_module        modules/libphp7.so
   LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
```

to run php 7 :

```
  LoadModule php7_module        modules/libphp7.so
   #LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
```

5- start xampp

Comment: Did you install both XAMPPs into the same /opt/lampp directory? XAMPP's installation wizard does not allow to choose installation directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't load phpmyadmin while I'm on php5 using this method

Answer (score 1):

I have tried multiple solutions for a run multiple PHP version in ubuntu system but nothing work perfectly then I try to install XAMMP and LAMP both separate

Please follow these steps

- Download LAMP 7.* version from [here](https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/installer)
- Download XAMMP 5.* version from [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)
- Install LAMP
- INSTALL XAMPP

NOTE: This solution work for me perfectly

Answer (score 0):

just install it into 2 different directories e.g. c:\xampp5 and c:\xampp7

edit: just realised you use ubuntu so i'm not sure if this will work but thats how I have done it using windows

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

I've used Bitnami Lamp Stack Installer for Ubuntu 16.04.
In Nutshell, I've Php 7.0.27 and 5.6.33 side-by-side.

Download Link: **https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/installer**


Steps I've followed:

1. I installed 7.0.27 installer in '/opt/lamp/7.0.27/' as primary so it could take port 80.

2. I created a shortcut for this is version. I started it and checked it's working or not.

3. Leaving 7.0.27 version started, I started installing 5.6.33 installer.

4. It asked me Default port, SSL Port, and Mysql Port. I used 8888, 444, 3307 respectively.

5. Done.


I have PHP version 7.0.27 running on 'localhost' and PHP version 5.6.33 running on 'localhost:8888'