# Update PHP Version of XAMPP on macOS

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I’m fairly new to mac and try to learn some things by playing around.
Currently I’m trying to get an new PHP version on XAMPP running on my macbook. I've read different threads and tutorials for this (e.g. [Is there way to use two PHP versions in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp)) but I'm stuck. Here is what I got:

macOS Mojave with XAMPP 5.6.31-0 with PHP version 5.6.31

`$ which PHP` says `/usr/bin/php`

`$ PHP -v`  says `7.1.19`

So this means macOS has PHP7 out of the box?
So I tried to make XAMPP load PHP7 from the mac path by editing the `/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf` by:

```
<IfDefine JUSTTOMAKEAPXSHAPPY>
#LoadModule php4_module        modules/libphp4.so
#LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
LoadModule php7_module         /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
</IfDefine>
```

But after restarting the apache `phpinfo()` stays hat `5.6.31`. Even if I delete the PHP 7 + 5 lines and expect PHP4 to be loaded it stays at 5.

So what am I doing wrong?

Disclaimer: I know it would be the easiest way to download a newer XAMPP version or use the build in apache from mac. But for learning reasons I would like to get this done.

Comment: I personally wouldn't use XAMPP at all. Installing PHP through homebrew is much easier. The only thing left is to manually start the PHP server each time. However, this can be done from every folder, so the root is dynamic :-). I've had much nightmares from XAMPP. That is why I use the homebrew version.

Comment: Why are you doing this at all? macOS comes with PHP 7.1.19 and Apache 2.4.34. That's more than good enough for any local development you might need to do.

Comment: Have you tried dumping ``$_SERVER["COMSPEC"]`` to see which PHP executable is being run?

Comment: @miken32 Laravel 8 version does not work on 7.1.19 so we will have to update php version. Kindly suggest how can we do? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 21):

The best way is install Homebrew, and then in your terminal, write this:

```
$ brew upgrade php // upgrade php formula
$ brew install php@7.2
$ brew link php@7.2 // create an alias to this keg-only version; see comments output during installation
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile // add the alias to your path; see comments output during installation
$ source ~/.bash_profile // reload .bash_profile to use the new settings immediately
```

greetings!

Comment: one minor fix. Change  $ brew update php to $ brew upgrade php

Comment: It's actually not fixed though

Comment: Unless I am mistaken this does not change the version of PHP in XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research and implementation, the best one that works for me without using the homebrew command this

- go to this link   https://php-osx.liip.ch/#install
- copy the url of the php version you want to install
- paste it inside your terminal, it will require for your password, kindly provide it
- After installation is complete, add the default path of php to your bash profile by doing this `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` you can simply copy and paste, after check your php version. i believe it will have change.

Comment: After install completed. done the export. but still, the PHP version showing as 7.2.21

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your localhost PHPmyAdmin, click on "Export" and export all the databases as one.
2. Go to your XAMPP folder, go to the "Htdocs" folder and copy all your project files to a different folder outside the XAMPP folder.
3. Go to the XAMPP folder and click the uninstall icon. It will remove xampp. I noticed it leaves your database and htdocs folder intact. Steps 1 and 2 were just a precaution.
4. Go to and download the latest XAMPP that has the PHP version you want. You can find it at https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html
5. Click on the downloaded file and install it. It will complete and you will have the PHP version you want install and your Htdocs and database will be intact. In case your database and htdocs is not there, simply recopy the project files you copied and import the database you exported.