# I have a problem when I run two version of PHP on Xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I have PHP 7 in my Xampp but I want to run an older project in PHP 5 and codeigniter, so when I was setting up for two version of PHP on Xampp with config httpd-xampp.conf in according to the way (Add Directories to run specific PHP version) was in Stack Overflow in this link [Is there way to use two PHP versions in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp), then I browse localhost/my_older_project I got many warning:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\xampp\php\ext\bz2' -
> The specified module could not be found.
>
> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\xampp\php\ext\curl' -
> The specified module could not be found.
>
> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> 'c:\xampp\php\ext\fileinfo' - The specified module could not be found.
>
> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> 'c:\xampp\php\ext\php_ftp.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Instead of doing changing php version,  you can just download wamp with php 5.6 to run along with xampp

Comment: @AdityaThakur Thank's ...

Comment: Can you explain which parts of these warnings are unclear to you?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating two versions of php, its better idea to simply use another webserver like wamp to run parallel with your xampp. If it port conflict occurs, you can simply change the port in either one's config.