# Use alternate version of PHP with Git Bash / Windows 8.1

Tags: php

I'm on Windows 8.1 with multiple PHP versions installed under Xampp using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49586592/429523).

In VSCode I'm using the Git Bash terminal.

The default version of PHP is set to 5.6. So running the command:

```
php -version
```

results in:

```
PHP 5.6.30 (cli)...
```

How can I temporarily run php 7.3 from the terminal?

- php.exe for 7.3 is here: C:\xampp\php73

Comment: Just call it directly from your command prompt: `C:\xampp\php73\php.exe <your-script>`

Comment: Also your title and question doesn't match

Comment: This is what I personally did when I had to run two PHP versions on Windows using XAMPP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45881681/408777

Comment: @catcon Thanks: "C:\xampp\php73\php.exe" --version (in quotes works). Sorry about the title - early morning pre-coffee post - fixed now.

Comment: It's best if the comment above will be posted as an answer. It will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to call the appropriate version with the full path. In this case:

```
"C:\xampp\php73\php.exe" --version
```