# How can I run 2 different Xampps/Lampp at a same time?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, xampp, yum, lampp

I have already installed lampp which is having version 7.2 currently.
I need to run, another version of php 5.6 at a same time, fine if running on a different port.

I have also referred this  [Reference Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp), but it is of windows.

I have done similar thing in windows,by installing two xampps and placing in 2 different directories and running at different ports.

I want to do that same on AWS server, well I dont have GUI to do so, I have installed lampp. Can anyone help me out to run two different lampp or xampp at a same time?

Well the server is aws linux and I have only option of Yum packages only as System administrator think, it is more secured.

Comment: What specifically did you try and what goes wrong?

Comment: Why would you want to do that though?

Comment: Well I try to install lampp again bt it is overwriting it

Comment: @GROVER.two different sites at different versions, requirement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp

Comment: @catcon, that is the solution for windowsa\

Comment: similar concept though

Answer (score 1):

1. Consider using Docker. This is right way, but you have to properly set it
2. Probably you can set up different ports in different versions of Xampp. But if you want to use different versions of PHP CLI, you should type full path to PHP executable every time you want to use it.