# Problem Setting two PHP version on XAMPP on Windows

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am running a XAMPP installation with PHP 5.6 for compatibility reason with my existing projects, but my new project requires PHP 7+.
I'm trying to install PHP 7.4 alongside my existing PHP 5.6 following the guide in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp) question, but I only end up in a 404 page for that project.
My `httpd-xampp.conf` looks like this

```
#
# XAMPP settings
#

<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
#</FilesMatch>
#<IfModule actions_module>
#    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
#</IfModule>


<IfModule php5_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/xampp/php/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
          Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
    <IfModule php5_module>
        <Files "status.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /security "C:/xampp/security/htdocs/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/security/htdocs">
        <IfModule php5_module>
            <Files "xamppsecurity.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
   </Directory>

    Alias /licenses "C:/xampp/licenses/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/licenses">
        Options +Indexes
        <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
            DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
            DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
            DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
        </IfModule>
        Require all granted
   </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "C:/xampp/webalizer/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/webalizer">
        <IfModule php5_module>
            <Files "webalizer.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>

# Begin multi-php modifications
Listen 8081

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/xampp/php7/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php7">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
          Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:8081 "C:/xampp/Telegram"> <--originally was C:/xampp/htdocs/Telegram
#    UnsetEnv PHPRC                      <-- Tried to enable/disable this and the above settings, unsuccessfully
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php74-cgi
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>

#End multi-php modifications
```

I feel there's something in the default settings forcing xampp to run PHP 5.6 and only scripts from the `./htdocs` directory, but since I'm quite noob about xampp configuration, I'm asking here what to do.
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCE56.jpg) the result from Postman, trying to connect to the project.

P.S. without the multi-PHP modifications the page loads "correctly" (considering the PHP 7 requisite)

Comment: You may try this  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp"

Comment: @dEL it is EXACLTY the link I posted in the introduction lol I was following that