# XAMPP 2 instances on one server

Tags: php, xampp

I want to run 2 XAMPP instances on a Windows 2016 server.
1 XAMPP version 3.2.4 is already running:
[image]

Now version 3.2.4 has default PHP7x running and I need PHP5 also for a website. I tried to run PHP5 on the same instance. And for this I tried to follow: [Is there way to use two PHP versions in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp#:~:text=You%20can%20have%20two%20different,18%5Cxampp).

Unfortunately I could not make it work. So I went for another approach and that is installing another version of XAMPP on the same server. I went for version 3.2.2. I changed the ports like stated in this url: [How to change XAMPP apache server port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)
But still doesnt work. Seems that my apache is hanging. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Can anyone help me to get the 3.2.2 running? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you change the ports on one of the xammp instances

Comment: I would recommend ditching xammp as a dev enviroment, some of the newer tech alternatives has made strides. like docker or using a linux vm with vagrant

Comment: I already changed the ports to 8080 and 4443. Ports are not used and free but still not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. This is how to fix it: Change Apache service name. And then, while Apache is not running,  click on the red cross (in the screenshot you see a green check mark but this was a red cross first) this will install Apache. Then run localhost en go to http://localhost:8080 and now its working. Two XAMPPs running at the same time.

Screenshot of chaning the Apache service name (you can go here by clicking on the Config button which you see also in the screenshot at the upper right corner):

[image]

In services you can see that there are two Apache running now from two XAMPP installations:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. To avoid similar conflicts with MySQL, I also had to set it to another port for one of the instances. This is done by clicking the "Config" button and editing "my.ini". One has to set port=3307 (or else) instead of port=3306 at two locations.