# Is i t possible to run PHP version 4.x with no cgi.exe on Xampp?

Tags: php, xampp

I've tried this [Is there way to use two PHP versions in XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp/45905822)

PHP version 4.3.4 does not have nts install. So there's no php-cgi.exe.Then I tried to run php.exe instead of php-cgi.exe by making change in the file below. It doesn't seem to work. Is there any way I can run this php version on Xampp?

Here is  my httpd-xampp.conf file

```
ScriptAlias /php43/ "C:/xampp/php43/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php43">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php.exe">
          Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Listen 85
<VirtualHost *:85>
UnsetEnv PHPRC
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
    php_flag engine off
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php43
    Action application/x-httpd-php43 "php43/php.exe"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: PHP4? That's about 20 years old, do you have any really specific requirements to run PHP4?

Comment: I need to fix code on old project  haha

Comment: Most likely, maintain a project written 10 years ago by a "senior" with ten times a year of experience ;-)

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work". What are the symptoms? Have you checked Apache logs? What's your Apache version and architecture?

Comment: sry for the late response. I looked at the log and it says "Invalid URI in request 'php43/php.exe/test/index.php' ".