# XAMPP Apache service not starting?

Tags: mysql, sql, apache, xampp, uac

I have tried everything:

1. Reinstalling the app 5 times
2. Changing the ports from 80 to 8080 and
   443 to 4343
3. Using the Apache start BAT file
4. Looking online for further solutions.
5. Changing UAC settings (though note that I don't
   know if I necessarily disabled it. The setting is called "Never
   notify me")
6. I uninstalled Skype (I mean not like I use it anyway)

The official error in the control panel:

```
3:27:24 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
3:27:24 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
3:27:24 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
3:27:24 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
3:27:24 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
3:27:24 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
3:27:24 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Error in the logs:

```
[Fri Jul 24 15:27:23.908527 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 1800:tid 664] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jul 24 15:27:23.958604 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 1800:tid 664] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Fri Jul 24 15:27:23.958604 2020] [:emerg] [pid 1800:tid 664] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
```

Any solutions?

Comment: To fix this one `PHP Warning: 'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP` Install ALL the Visual C/C++ Runtimes from the Microsoft site, but I did think the one you need would have been installed with XAMPP, but I am not a XAMPP user

Comment: Here are the Visual CC programs that I have: 2015-2019(x86 and x64), 4 installations of the 2013 redist (2 x86 and 2 x64), 2012 (x86 and x64), 2010 (x86 and x64), 4 installations of the 2008 redist (3 x86 and 1 x64), and the last is a 2005 redist

Comment: What version of PHP Are you using

Comment: I dunno, I don't think I installed that  sry

Comment: It comes with XAMPP

Comment: In that case I dont know where I can check that, any tips? I'm new to this stuff and I need to complete it as a course for IB Comp Sci

Comment: Run the XAMPP Control panel and I would guess it will say on there

Comment: I just installed it, my computer is currently at home I'll check it later

Comment: The version of 2015-2019 that you should check for is 14.16.28720

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the latest version of Visual studio from Microsoft. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look on log, looks like that the server name is different that the name on the SSL certificate.

Comment: Requesting a new certificate with the correct server name.

Comment: Now how do I do THAT? I'm really sorry I'm not really experienced in this stuff 

Answer (score 0):

The problem usually can be caused by `point (5) Changing UAC settings`. By installing `vcruntime140.dll` do not solve the problem.
This can be caused by installing other version of php or the different of php version (uninstal the php and try to instal the XAMPP again).

Source:
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp` and `https://themanish.com/run-multiple-version-of-php-in-xampp-windows-without-installing-multiple-xampp/`