# Tell Command Line which PHP version to use

Tags: php, windows, xampp, environment-variables, command-line-interface

i have 2 versions of php. **PHP 5.6** located at C:\xampp and **PHP 7** located at D:\xampp749. How to tell the cli to use php 7 when im running on D:\xampp749?

ps: when checking the phpinfo, the version is accurate it uses php 7 and 5.6 respectively. i also added this in the environment variables **D:\xampp749\php**

[image: ers]

[image]

Comment: Specify the full path to the php binary when calling it?

Comment: you can change which version of php required in xamp manager

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp, but not sure if it fits what you are asking.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz can u provide me an example sir?. i don't quite understand

Comment: `D:\xampp749\php\php.exe your_script.php` or `C:\xampp\php\php.exe your_script.php`

Comment: @LarsStegelitz it's not working sir

Comment: "not working" is not helpful...