# How to set up multiple php version in one computer?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I am going to several sites with php framework - Laravel, but each laravel framework requires different php versions.
I want to set up xampp in one computer, so I am going to develop on various kinds of php versions.
What shall I do? Using docker is somewhat complicated, other way else?

Comment: Docker is a best way to afford each configuration for each project. You can find a lot of examples of docker start for your laravel project, your symfony project etc etc.

however maybe set some alias for some php version but i don't know how you can say "this php version for this project".

Comment: You can directly run multi php in one computer.Make php listent on different port or socket.

Comment: Docker or use laragon where you can swtch anytime php version from dropdown

Comment: Think this may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790160/is-there-way-to-use-two-php-versions-in-xampp

Comment: Other than changing php version, Changing Xampp version is more useful, I think. Installing multiple xampp in other directories is difficult?

Comment: @seopine if you install multiple xampp it can be conflict with port's

Comment: @seopine check this artical   for multiple php in laragon i use same thing https://medium.com/@oluwaseye/add-different-php-versions-to-your-laragon-installation-d2526db5c5f1

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative called MAMP. With MAMP PRO, you can edit the PHP version for each project you have running without any kind of edits to the files.

It automatically edits the hostfile for you aswell, and you can enable a lot of extra known php extentions in the setting.

You don't have to worry about installing multiple applications or interfering with different ports. It's basically press and play