# Change CLI PHP version for specific project

Tags: php, apache, command-line-interface, phpstorm

One project needs an older PHP version 7.0.

I followed [this guide from JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-local-interpreter.html) to configure the PHP Interpreter, but even after restarting Apache, terminating the shell, restarting PhpStorm it didn't work.

[image]

So I decided to try it differently, so I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49586592/9013718) on how to run two PHP versions at the same time with XAMPP, I followed everything to the letter, but when typing `php -v` it still does not show the wanted PHP version.

Am I missing out on something?

Comment: If you want the cli version, this has nothing to do with apache.

Comment: Okay, thank you but how do I change the cli version?

Comment: If you need another PHP version **for CLI only**... then download PHP from windows.php.net (since you are on Windows OS) and do a minimal needed configuration in php.ini.

Comment: If it **has to be the part of XAMPP** (so they both can use 2 diff PHP) .. then it's a diff question. **In any case:** the path to PHP executable should be different for different versions. Type `where php` to see the current path for `php` executable (e.g. when you run `php.exe artisan xx` command from Laravel or alike). The terminal (to be precise: Windows) looks for executable from folders from `PATH` environment variable. If you need to put your PHP version for CLI -- prepend such path there .. or use full path to the executable file.

Comment: Well it's a Symfony application that I need to run locally. I intended to use the Symfony local https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html, but that is to open in the browser, right? 
I need to update composer packages first, and I get the error that my PHP version is too recent, that's why I need a 7.0 CLI.
I already downloaded PHP 7 for windows and tried to configure it in PhpStorm. I don't see the relation to "do a minimal needed configuration in php.ini" though.

Comment: BTW -- setting up different PHP Interpreter in PhpStorm and switching between them there will NOT affect the Terminal in any way. The PHP Interpreter in PhpStorm is used for: 1) to run/debug your PHP file using "PHP Script" type of configuration (a CLI environment); 2) to run PHP based tools (e.g. PHPUnit, CodeSniffer, Composer and alike); 3) by PhpStorm's built-in simple web server (limited one, not worth using when you have proper web server).

Comment: As you can see in the image, I typed `which php` and that gives me the same result as `where php` and that is not the path to the version I want.
"switching between them there will NOT affect the Terminal in any way"
oh alright that explains, I didnt know this. Now the question is: how can I change the php in the CLI for this specific project (that `where php` shows the path to php7) do I have to change something in the `PATH` variable?

Comment: Do you really need that to be for `php` command? Have you tried using the full path to the needed php.exe instead of just `php`? It may work.

Comment: If you need this then I may suggest this: 1) launch `cmd.exe`; 2) just type `PATH` there and execute it -- it will show the current paths used by OS to find executable files. 3) Add path to your PHP 7.0 version (`C:\xampp\php7`) in front -- e.g. `SET PATH=C:\xampp\php7\;%PATH%` -- something like that should work. *If I'm not mistaken this should work for the current session only (especially if cmd is not run as Admin)*

Comment: If you need to alter the `PATH` permanently -- do it via GUI I guess. You need to go into the System Properties for that, e.g. 1) press `Win + I` 2) Go to `System`, then `About`. 3) Scroll down to the end to "Related Settings" section -- choose `Advanced System Settings` there. 4) On that new old-style dialog, on "Advanced" tab, click on `Environment variables` button, find the `PATH` and edit it there. Once done you may need to restart apps/session as evn vars are part of process on Windows (have own copy when launched).

Comment: It was a really good idea to use the full path for this one command but there is exception after exception with composer.

Comment: In such case: see the previous 2 comments about changing the `PATH` variable. You can also try the following but I think it may not work as desired: place the symlink in the current folder (at least temporarily) -- `php.exe` and point it to the needed `C:\xampp\php7\php.exe`. May work .. but I think it most likely will fail to load php extensions/correct php config.

Comment: Exceptions were not related to this I think I posted an answer. 
Thank you so much @LazyOne genuinely, I appreciate your time. Means a lot to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thousand thanks to @LazyOne which gave me the solution.
As I only need PHP 7 to run `composer update` for one project, it is way simpler to use the full path instead of configuring the `PATH` env variable.
This worked for me:

1. Install the right PHP version from [here](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/)
2. Extract the files in new folder (I called it `php7`)
3. Copy `php.ini-development` to `php.ini`
4. Open it and remove the `;` before `; extension_dir = "ext"` and `; extension=openssl`
5. Run the command with the full path

```sh
"C:\xampp\php7\php.exe" "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" update
```

Et voilà.

Unfortunately though, this didn't work out for me as I had many exceptions, but not really related to this question (`Fatal error: Attempted to load class "Redis" from the global namespace`) as the update command did start the update process.