# How to downgrade PHP 5.6 to PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, xampp, web

Do you know **how to downgrade php from 5.6 to 5.3**?

I created a website with PHP 5.6 but when my client uploaded on their server some functions on my website are not compatible and they say that the problem is because their PHP version is 5.3 and I don't know about it, so they want me to downgrade my PHP version. Can you help me?

Or any solution to my problem? So, my website can be compatible on their server.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397219/how-to-downgrade-php-from-5-5-to-5-3 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to downgrade php from 5.5 to 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397219/how-to-downgrade-php-from-5-5-to-5-3)

Comment: don't do that, the only right way to deal with this kind of problems is update, not downgrade. PHP 5.3 is too old anyway. Update the server, if they don't have any other php website running, its not a problem.

Answer (score -1):

You're most likely talking not about downgrading of the PHP executables, but about downgrading language level from 5.6 to 5.3

There is no automatic way to do it, but you can study syntax changes between versions (information can be found into [official manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/appendices.php)) and update your code accordingly.

Also it may be good idea to remind customer that PHP 5.3 [is not supported](https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php) anymore so it may be good idea to upgrade PHP version instead of downgrading site. 5.3 -> 5.6 upgrade is relatively plainless.